# I want to link the button to another page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i link this code to a page 2?

```
<div class="login">
<h1>Login</h1>

<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
<input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
 <button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large"></a>Let me in.</button>
```

Comment: Why do you have a `</a>` inside your `<button></button>` element? Anyway, it's a submit button, so you should just put an `action="yourPage2.something"` attribute on your `<form>` and then clicking the button will submit the input elements' values to the URL of your choice.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use that close tags `</a>`
you can give form to perform some action.

```
<form action="somewhere.html">
<input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
<input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
<button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Let me in.</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the 'a' tag it should look something like this:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com"><button type='button'>lets get social</button></a>
```

If you wish the new link to open up in a new tab/window you can add this into the 'a' tag: `target="_blank"`

```
ie: <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank">
```